# Potentially faulty or weird behavior for pandas.series.isin

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 tables in my database (`visits`, `events`).

visits has a primary key `visit_id`,
events_and_pages has a column `visit_id` which is sort of a foreign key of visits. (An `events` row can belong to 0 to 1 visit)

What I want to do: Filter-out from `events` table all the `visit_id` that don't belong to `visits` table. Simple task.

I have the data for each of those tables stored in `pandas.DataFrame`, respectively `df_visits` and `df_events`

I do the following operation :

`len(set(df_visits.visit_id) - set(df_events.visit_id))` I get a result of 1670, which is compliant with what I should expect.

But when I do

```
filter_real_v = df_events.visit_id.isin(set(visits.visit_id))
filter_real_v.value_counts() # I get only True values


filter_real_v = df_events.visit_id.isin(visits.visit_id)
filter_real_v.value_counts() # I get only True values
```

Even weirder, when I use

```
pd.DataFrame(df_events.visit_id).isin(real_visits)).visit_id.value_counts() #I get all False values except 8 that are True

pd.DataFrame(df_events.visit_id).isin(set(real_visits)).visit_id.value_counts() #I get all True values
```

What is going on here? And how can I define a filter for which `visit_id` exists in `events` but not in `visits`?

Please find [in this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17wwN6DNGoPrEelEztXMgnOkqG2ErWZrG), the `df_events` and `df_visits` csv files to reproduce this error (comma separated `index,visit_id`)

EDIT : Add snippet for minimal reproducible code:

1. Download the files in the link and put them in a `file_path_events` & `file_path_visits` of your chosing
2. Execute the code bellow:

```
import pandas as pd
events = pd.read_csv("df_events.csv")
events.set_index('index',inplace=True)
visits = pd.read_csv("df_visits.csv")
visits.set_index('index',inplace=True)
correct_delta = len(set(visits.visit_id) - set(events.visit_id))
print(correct_delta) #1670
filter_real_v = events.visit_id.isin(set(visits.visit_id))
bad_delta = filter_real_v.value_counts()
print(bad_delta[True]) #702680
```

Best regards

Comment: can you add the dataframes here in the question(doesnt have to be long i believe) instead of the link.

Comment: @anky_91 I tried, but it crashes my browser

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with your snippet, but alternately you could use `df.join(..., how='inner', on='visit_id')` or `how='left'`

Comment: You *need to provide a [mcve]* for questions seeking debugging help.

Comment: from your example it looks like visits.visit_id > events.visit_id by 1670 so you should expect events.visit_id to be in visits.visit_id and thus return all Trues?

Comment: @d_kennetz according to the documentation : `isin` `Return a boolean Series showing whether each element in the Series matches an element in the passed sequence of values exactly.`

Comment: Your `correct_delta` and `filter_real_v` look to be doing opposite things?  I'd expect `correct_delta` to be more in line with `visits.visit_id.isin(events.visit_id)`.

Comment: @root, Yup, I messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is behaving correctly, your just misinterpreting the set operation "-"

`len(set(df_visits.visit_id) - set(df_events.visit_id))`

Will return the values of **df_visits.visit_id** not in df_events.visit_id. **Note**: If values of df_events.visit_id are not in df_visits.visit_id they will **not** be represented here. This is how sets work.

For example:

```
set([1,2,3,9]) - set([9,10,11])

Output:
{1, 2, 3}
```

Notice how 10 or 11 do not show up in the answer. None of the second set will as a matter of fact. Only the values in the second set will be taken away from the first set.

With `isin()` you are effectively doing:

```
visits['visit_id'].isin(df_events['visit_id'].values).value_counts()

True     56071
False     1670

# Note 1670 is the exact same you got in your set operation
```

and **not**:

```
df_events['visit_id'].isin(visits['visit_id'].values).value_counts()

True    702680
```

Comment: Yup, I messed up

Comment: What about the
`pd.DataFrame(df_events.visit_id).isin(real_visits)).visit_id.value_counts() #I get all False values except 8 that are True`

`pd.DataFrame(df_events.visit_id).isin(set(real_visits)).visit_id.value_counts() #I get all True values`